# Needing help to get the next line from the scanner and assign the value to the Array element at position i

Tags: java, arrays

I'm really new to programming and I am having trouble trying to figure out how to write this line of code that I have to read the next line from the scanner and as assign the value to the candyArray at position i. I am also told that I need to incorporate the  readLine()  to advance the input cursor past the first line.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // File containing candy names
    File f = new File("candy.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    // Array of candy names
    String[] candyNames;

    // Number of names
    int numNames = sc.nextInt();
    // Move to the next line
    sc.nextLine();

    // Set the array size
    candyNames = new String[numNames];

    // Read each line and copy to array element
    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
    // Add the missing statement
    //The statement should get the next line from the scanner and assign
       //the value to the candyArray element at position i.
        candyNames[i].readLine(numNames);
     System.out.println("Adding " + candyNames[i]);
     }
```

Comment: just do  `candyNames[i]=sc.nextLine();`

Comment: There is no `readLine()` method in String class

Answer (score 0):

There is no `readLine()` method in String class . Replace `candyNames[i].readLine(numNames)` with `candyNames[i]=sc.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

The method nextLine() is only available on the scanner.  So if you ever need to call it, you need to do a:

```
sc.nextLine()
```

and it will return a string.  You need to assign it to something, just like you assign a regular string.

```
candyNames[i] = "test";
// or 
candyNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
```

Then the rest of the code should work, as you are using candyNames[i] as a string in the print statement.